# SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

1)I have a designer workflow with two conditions like multiple and single as selections e.g. 'Single' and 'Multiple'.

2)There are some options with check boxes below the selections e.g. A , B , C and D.

3)If the user selects 'Single' as option and selects the check box A below, an email will be sent to the A and subject saying "User selected A and here is you what to do"

4)If he selects 'Multiple' as option and selects B and C, an email should be sent to both B and C saying "User selected B and C and here is what you need to do"

I was able to send mails in both cases but am unable to make how to mention two check boxes B and C in subject when they select multiple selection as option.

Please help me out in this scenario.

Comment: When building the subject line, use the String Builder option, then add a lookup for the column and choose display names instead of values.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Omegacron my scenario is different ...I got it other way i took a variable and wrote two different messages in it and when the email To value is equals to option than the message would be delivered took time to think though. but worked like charm for me.. :-) –

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this column with multiple check box:

> 1 , 2 , 3

When you tick checkbox **1**,

sharepoint will return this :

> {"results":["1"]}

When you tick checkbox **1 & 3**,
sharepoint will return this:

> {"results":["1","3"]}

I think that you can play with condition and the result for doing what you want.

I hope that it be helpful.

Cordialy,
EGuidez